# Is there a software platform for generic stats tracking?

Tags: web-services

Tracking and graphing statistics that happen in an application is a very common thing.  Are there any open source solutions out there that let you define arbitrary statistics, log events against those statistics, and then it handles the storage and display of those stats?

If it had pretty graphs, that's a bonus.

Obviously, it's easy to custom-develop a solution.  But this seems like one of those infrastructure things that doesn't have to be re-invented every time.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since asking this a few years back, I've found the ELK stack.

- Elastic Search - https://www.elastic.co/products/elasticsearch
- LogStash - https://www.elastic.co/products/logstash
- Kibana - https://www.elastic.co/products/kibana

It's perfect for this sort of thing, and can also consolidate ALL of your logging needs (http logs, etc)